# React, Update form state in generic way

Tags: reactjs

I am following the pattern for React Forms with Typescript. After each object member is changed, I write this to update the state.

We have 10+ fields. Is there any generic way of updating the fields, with properly methodology in React Typescript? Below seems repetitive. Is use of `any` recommended?

There is a mix of textboxes, dropdowns, and checkboxes in our form.

https://onestepcode.com/creating-a-material-ui-form/

```
  const onProductNameChange = (e: string) => {
    setProductFilter({
      ...productFilter,
      productName: e,
    });
  };

  const onProductStatusChange = (e: string) => {
    setProductFilter({
      ...productFilter,
      productStatus: e,
    });
  };


  const onLocationsChange = (e: Array<number>) => {
    setProductFilter({
      ...productFilter,
      serviceLocations: e,
    });
  };

  const onProvidersChange = (e: Array<number>) => {
    setProductFilter({
      ...productFilter,
      providers: e,
    });
  };
```

....
....

```
  <TextField
    value={product.feeName}
    label="Search by name"
    onChange={event => {
      onProductNameChange(event.target.value);
    }}
    }
  />
   <TextField
    value={product.productStatus}
    label="status"
    onChange={event => {
      onProductStatusChange(event.target.value);
    }}
    }
  />
```

Comment: Have you thought about using `onSubmit` rather than `onChange` ?

Comment: we don't have a submit button, form api gets called on blur for textboxes and onclose for dropdowns cc @BoshraJaber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any generic way of updating the fields

**Yes, there is.**

If we assign a name or any other defining characteristic to each `TextField`,
then we could use a single function for all of them.

**Example:**

```
function handleChange(event) {
   setProductFilter({
      ...productFilter,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
   })
}


<TextField
   name='productName'
   value={product.feeName}
   label="Search by name"
   onChange={handleChange}
/>

<TextField
   name='productStatus'
   value={product.productStatus}
   label="Search by name"
   onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

What we do here is assign the newly given value to the field within the state that has the same `name` as it's corresponding `TextField`.

Comment: is it possible to use keyOf Property in the other answer above, incase the state member name changes, we can send off a compilation error in VS code? thanks

Comment: I was thinking of using this function,  export function nameof<T>(name: keyof T): keyof T {
  return name;
}.  if you want to include in answer, I can send points, thanks !

Comment: I understand what you mean but not sure what would be the best way to implement it ATM. I'll give it some thought and comment if I come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to pass the name of the property you want to update as an argument using `keyof {Type}`. The downside to this is that you lose the static typing on the value.

```
const onProductChange = (key: keyof ProductFilter, value: any) => {
  setProductFilter({
    ...productFilter,
    [key]: value,
  });
};
```

...

```
<TextField
  value={product.feeName}
  label="Search by name"
  onChange={event => {
    onProductChange('name', event.target.value);
  }}
/>
```